# Command line options in SBT native packager

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

When you package a *command-line* application in SBT using the *sbt-native-packager* plugin, you get a wrapper script that has additional command line options that looks something like this:

```
  -h | -help         print this message
  -v | -verbose      this runner is chattier
  -d | -debug        set sbt log level to debug
  -no-version-check  Don't run the java version check.
  -mem <integer>     set memory options in MB (default: , which is -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m)
  -jvm-debug <port>  Turn on JVM debugging, open at the given port.

  # java version (default: java from PATH, currently java version "1.7.0_21")
  -java-home <path>         alternate JAVA_HOME

  # jvm options and output control
  JAVA_OPTS          environment variable, if unset uses ""
  -Dkey=val          pass -Dkey=val directly to the java runtime
  -J-X               pass option -X directly to the java runtime
                     (-J is stripped)

  # special option
  --                 To stop parsing built-in commands from the rest of the command-line.
                     e.g.) enabling debug and sending -d as app argument
                     $ ./start-script -d -- -d
```

Is it possible to either selectively disable some of this options or remove them altogether from the packaged application?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a way to customise the script template : http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/java_app/customize.html#start-script-customizations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there isn't any way to *disable* single command line options.

However, you can do a few other things:

1. [As Shyam mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37533693/command-line-options-in-sbt-native-packager#comment62566153_37533693), you can [override the start script](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/java_app/customize.html#start-script-customizations)
2. The second option would be to use the **`--`** separator. Everything before that will be parsed by the script, and everything after will be appended as command line arguments to the application.

If you have a use case that may be of interest for general availability, you can open a feature request.

Comment: Thanks @muki I will try the first option. I know about the second but it is quite un-natural for distributable applications where the users doesn't have to know about the existence of two step command line parsing

Answer (score 1):

For the Bash script, you can add this to your SBT configuration:

`bashScriptExtraDefines += """set -- -- "$@""""`

This effectively prepends a `--` to the passed in command line arguments, which will be consumed by the wrapper. The wrapper then passes through everything after this prepended `--`.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable all of them altogether platform-independently by appending `--` to the java options:

```
javaOptions in Universal += "--"
```

This has to be the last java option, so that it is injected after you've set any custom java options you already might have. Clearly this is quite hacky, as `--` is not really a java option, but currently native-packager does not check that it is.